# creating multiple subscribers/service activators to spring channel programatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Am trying to utilize Spring integration SI in my application, am creating channels and service activators programatically, I have 2 questions, first, am doing the **logic** of message processing in the service activator process method, is that anti-pattern ?

```
@Component
public abstract class IChannelProcessor {

    @Loggable
    Logger logger;

    public void handleMessage(Message<IMessage> message) {

        try {

            boolean messagePreprocessed = false, messageProcessed = false, messagePostprocessed = false;

            messagePreprocessed = preProcessMessage(message);
            if (messagePreprocessed)
                messageProcessed = processMessage(message);
            if (messageProcessed)
                messagePostprocessed = postProcessMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean preProcessMessage(Message<IMessage> message);

    public abstract boolean processMessage(Message<IMessage> message);

    public abstract boolean postProcessMessage(Message<IMessage> message);
}
```

and later I subscribe to channels as below

```
channelProcessor = (IChannelProcessor) obj;
                        serviceActivatorHandler = new ServiceActivatingHandler(channelProcessor, "handleMessage");
                        String processorChannelName = config.get(processName, Constants.PARAMETER_KEY_CHANNEL);
                        utils.createInputChannel(processorChannelName).subscribe(serviceActivatorHandler);
```

is that okey, or service activator should forward message to another end-point to take the action.

second question is, am trying to create multiple consumers (threads) to the channel, noting that I need to ensure message is being processed only once.

I found dispatched in addition to taskExecutor can achive that, how can I acheive similar thing programatically in java

```
<int:channel id="receiverChannel">
       <int:dispatcher task-executor="workerThreadExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
<task:executor id="workerThreadExecutor" pool-size="15" queue-capacity="10"  rejection-policy="DISCARD" />
<int:service-activator id="worker" ref="workerThread" method="process" input-channel="receiverChannel" />
<bean id="workerThread" class="com.uppi.poc.throttler.WorkerThread" />
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Fully not sure why do you need to create a service activator on the fly and do all that "hard core" manually. To make the parallel work you indeed should use an `ExecutorChannel` in Java.

Comment: service activators are created based on specific logic, this is why am doing it manually, and I want to know how to implement the XML logic programatically